# order.getEmailCustomerNote() blank in emails

Tags: onepage-checkout, magento-2.2.5

In my order confirmation email template I'm trying to output the following:

`{{var order.getEmailCustomerNote()}}`

However it does not show up. The comment taken during the order is however visible on the order notes page. It is stored in the sales_order table as customer_note.

I am using One Page Checkout.

Can anyone think of a reason this wouldn't appear, or the first place to look?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this was specific to the One Page Checkout extension I was using, but I needed getCustomerNote() rather than getEmailCustomerNote() mentioned in the magento docs, as such could be output like this

```
{{if order.getCustomerNote()}}
Order comments:
{{var getCustomerNote()|escape|nl2br}}
{{/if}}
```